# Working with location-based breadcrumbs when you are missing some parent pages

Tags: breadcrumbs

So I am working on a small LMS system and am I trying to find a way make it easier to navigate the system using breadcrumbs.

When the admin logs in, he starts on the Courses page which presents a listing of all the courses. For each course in the list, there is an Actions dropdown with options: Edit Course, Manage Tutorials, etc. There is no "main" or "parent" page for the course; you either edit the course or manage its different resources (tutorials, quizzes, files, etc). Below is the page:

[image]

Let's say the admin wants to edit tutorials in a course, they would click on Manage Tutorials for the particular course and go to the Tutorials page. Below is the page:

[image]

Notice how the breadcrumb looks like `Courses / Tutorials`. Ultimately, I would like to do something like this `Courses / STAB27 / Tutorials` in order to get rid of the heading e.g. "STAB27 - Statistics II".

This might sound silly/trivial but the problem is: should "STAB27" in the desired trail necessarily be a link? If so, where should it point to (as I do not have any parent page except for the Edit Course page)? What is the convention to deal with situations like this?

I follow this same pattern as I go deeper in levels. For example, one page has a trail as `Courses / Quizzes / Questions` and would prefer to make it look like `Courses / STAB27 / Quizzes / Quiz 1 / Questions`.

**Edit as asked**

When creating a new quiz for a course,

1) The admin clicks on Manage Quizzes option in the Actions dropdown (in the first image). This brings them to the Quizzes page that list all the quizzes.

2) The admin will click on a button, Add New Quiz, to bring them to a page to fill out and save.

3) Once saved, the admin will be brought back to the Quizzes page. The new quiz, Quiz 1, will appear in the list.

[image]

4) The admin will then click Manage Questions to bring them to the Questions page that list all the questions for the particular quiz.

5) The admin will click a button, Add New Question, to bring them to a page to fill out and save.

6) Once saved, the admin will be brought back to the Questions page. The new question will appear in the list.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered  `Courses / STAB27 Tutorials`? This is, making the course name part of the subsection link?

Comment: Hm.. I have not considered that. How would you deal with deeper levels such as the one in my last paragraph?

Comment: Why does your "root" have breadcrumps? Having a link which just points to yourself seems unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach that comes to mind:

> [Courses](http://nolink123.com/courses)
>   [Courses](http://nolink123.com/courses) - STAB27: [Tutorials](http://nolink123.com/courses/stab27/tutorials)
>   [Courses](http://nolink123.com/courses) - STAB27: [Quizzes](http://nolink123.com/courses/stab27/quizzes) / [Quiz 1](http://nolink123.com/courses/stab27/quizzes/1) / [Questions](http://nolink123.com/courses/stab27/questions)

Just "Courses", "Tutorials", "Quizzes", "Quiz 1", and "Questions" are links. The course name is not a link.

Comment: This might just be the approach I need to use for my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the pages you are describing are not really pages (as they dont have an address assigned) but [Dialogs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html).

As far as I understood you have this (marked) pages:

> **Courses** | STAB27 | **Quizzes** | **Quiz 1** | Questions

So in order to manage the breadcrumbs you could design them this way:

> **Courses** / **STAB27 Quizzes** / **Quiz 1**

And use the same format for the different sub-pages of the course:

> **Courses** / **STAB27 Tutorials**
>
> **Courses** / **STAB27 Instructors**
>
> **Courses** / **STAB27 Students**

My suggestion is to rethink it and see if you could include a page for those missing breadcrumbs, specially "course".

Comment: Thanks. Only issue with the first way: where would Quiz 1 point to (as it also does not have a page) ? In terms of the second way, I was trying to avoid creating additional pages.

Comment: Then the same (ill edit the answer), but it gets a bit tricky, so rethink if you really should avoid creating a course page.

Comment: Please check the edit. There are no pages for Course, Quiz 1 or Questions, right?

Comment: You're right - it does get tricky (and messier). Precisely, there are no individual pages for courses, quizzes, and questions. Just there edit pages.

Comment: @Mikey Im not sure about this last edit of the Questions. If you could update the question with an example of how to create Questions on a Quiz, it might be more helpful.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example on how a question is created.

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if I didn't understand it correctly.